# Url de uma requisição POST

Tags: php, libcurl

Olá, bom(a) dia/tarde/noite!

Estou desenvolvendo um plugin para gerar boletos no Woocommerce, no caso preciso enviar os dados de um formulário para o banco a fim de obter o boleto e exibir para o cliente.

Optei por fazer isto utilizando o PHP-Curl, que achei a melhor opção. Bom, consegui enviar os dados do formulário via POST e receber o boleto, mas falta uma última coisa, a URL gerada pelo banco, que é o necessário para imprimir uma segunda via do boleto, caso seja necessário.

Sabem me informar se é possível "pegar" esta URL com o Curl?

Segue o meu código atual, se ajudar

```
$fields = array com os dados do formulário

$url = 'https://geraboleto.sicoobnet.com.br/geradorBoleto/GerarBoleto.do';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

$result = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Bem vindo Rodrigo, traga mais detalhes na pergunta, por exemplo como vem essa url do banco, se já tem uma consulta retornando.

Comment: @AndréLins, na verdade o banco me enviou apenas um formulário html, então sei a propriedade name dos <inputs> que utilizei no array $fields, e a $url estou usando a url da propriedade action do formulário.
Infelizmente isto é tudo que tenho para trabalhar.

Comment: Talvez você possa usar o curl_getinfo para obter algumas informações. Achei esse link para a documentação: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: o próprio `curl_exec` já traz uma resposta do servidor, que nesse caso, você armazenou em `$result`. Dê um `var_dump` em `$result` e vê se essa informação foi retornada pra você